# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'secret') while trying to set a response cookie in Express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying an operation I've done a hundred times yet it isn't going well today! For whatever reason I fail to set a refresh token cookie using Express.

Here is the full error

```
/home/me/Code/apGymBE/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:856
  var secret = this.req.secret;
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'secret')
    at ServerResponse.res.cookie (/home/me/Code/apGymBE/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:856:25)
    at AuthController.setTokenCookie (/home/me/Code/apGymBE/src/controllers/auth.controller.ts:296:18)
    at AuthController.<anonymous> (/home/me/Code/apGymBE/src/controllers/auth.controller.ts:73:14)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/me/Code/apGymBE/src/controllers/auth.controller.ts:28:58)
```

Here is the line that throws the error

```js
   private setTokenCookie(response: Response, token: string) {
        // create cookie with refresh token that expires in 7 days
        const cookieOptions = {
            httpOnly: true,
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        };
        console.log(token, "293"); // this executes
        response.cookie("refreshToken", token, cookieOptions); // this doesn't
    }
```

Here is an example console log from that one marked `//this executes`: `bfb8ed08109cf7d6f747406ac79c47d5cc8c709ab862d7cb8dc8c4b68ff547900feb0ece849cb8c2 293`

I am not sure what to do as none of the googles I've tried has yielded anything about this error message.

I tried:

(1) `this.app.use(cookieParser("temp"));` <= added a string arg to cookieParser. No change.

(2) adding express-session.

```
import session from "express-session";

// later...
        this.app.use(
            session({
                secret: secret,
                resave: false,
                saveUninitialized: true,
                cookie: { secure: true },
            }),
        );
```

Neither helped.

Not sure where to look.

edit: `npm install` also didnt make a difference (though why would it?)

edit2: I suspect the problem is from outside of the code I posted but the q is now, where?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Sorry, didn't give the OP the right info to aid in the quest. Previously I had

```
public async grantAccessToken(request: Request, res: Response) {
        const newUser = request.user as any;
        const ipAddress = request.ip;
        const accountDetails: IBasicDetails = await this.authService.grantRefreshToken(newUser, ipAddress);
        // todo: figure out where this response is sent - presumably to the frontend
        if (accountDetails.refreshToken === undefined) throw Error("refresh token missing from authenticate response");
        this.setTokenCookie(response, accountDetails.refreshToken);
        return response.json({ ...accountDetails, jwtToken: accountDetails.jwtToken });
    }
```

Changing `res` to `response` fixed it.